# Sending welcome emails asynchronously in python Flask application

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to send a welcome email to the user when he/she first logs (fb auth) into our flask application.

So I am thinking of using flask-mail for the email framework and celery (python client for rabbitmq) as a task queue.

So I have a simple email framework:

```
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from app import mail

    def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
        msg = Message(subject, sender = sender, recipients = recipients)
        msg.body = text_body
        msg.html = html_body
        mail.send(msg)
```

I have been reading the celery docs - but I am not sure how to create the tasks required to send emails. I know that Flask-mail needs the Flask application context to work correctly. And then I need the celery instance for celery as well. Should that be part of the flask app? In short I am looking for a little guidance. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You may want to check the _Asynchronous calls in Python_ section of [The Flask Mega-Tutorial, Part XI: Email Support](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support).

Comment: Alternatively, check out exim. It is a piece of software that you use as a mail server. You can configure it to accept the mail, which it then asynchronously puts into a queue and sends it to another, real mail server. Otherwise, you have asked generally how a celery task can be created to send e-mail. You've described something that is quite possible. The Celery task can import the Flask application and create a context. You shouldn't have an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with threads as shown in [Grinberg's tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support)

```
from threading import Thread

def threading(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thr = Thread(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thr.start()
    return wrapper

@threading
def send_email(subject, to, body, html=None):
    def send():
        try:
            mail.send(msg)
        except Exception as err:
            app.logger.error("Error during mail send: {0}".format(err))

    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message(subject, recipients=[to], body=body, html=html,
                      sender="welcome@myapp.net")

        send()
```

And then in your view you can call `send_email` and not have to wait

If you want to incorporate feedback (aka live information in case there's an error when sending the email) for the email, you should add a message broker (i.e rabbitmq, zeromq) and a task queue (i.e celery) to the implementation (and a way to poll asynchronously for messages from the UI). Although I don't think you really need something like this for welcome emails -unless you send them in batches, you can find an example of how to use such stuff [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html)

Comment: hi, the article is 11 year olds, so i wonder if we have better solution in 2023 or not?

Comment: you can either go with Celery and create email sending tasks as it was mentioned in the response above, or if you use Flask 2.0 use an extension like flask-mailing which makes use of asyncio to fully send async emails

Comment: thanks @John, i was wondering there's some way to do this without creating worker, celery and redis need to create worker to make it work. thanks in advance.